# How to suppress php cross origin redirect error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am calling a remote php file via ajax via

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'home.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        crossOrigin: true,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#home").trigger('reset');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { $("#home").trigger('reset');},
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

and this is the code in home.php

```
$url = 'http://api.example.com/post-data';

header("Location: $url", TRUE, 307);

return 'User Is Inserted';
```

I have this enabled

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

and i am able to call the url as i had hoped. However, on the client side i am getting this error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://api.example.com/post-data (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

For the fix, i want to be able to suppress any errors returned by the redirect code

`header("Location: $url", TRUE, 307);` or manipulate the error returned.

Is there some way i can hide the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked:...` from the client side developer panel?.

I am on shared hosting where the support team says that curl is enabled and that get_file_contents works but that's not the case. I am using php 7.

The php file

```
<?php

/**
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
*/

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: `Is there some way i can hide the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked:... from the client side developer panel?` No, there isn't. However, you shouldn't see that error if you've added the CORS headers correctly. Double check they are in the response in the console. If they're missing, ensure you're adding them in the right place in your PHP code.

Comment: `crossOrigin: true,` this option does not exist. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . There is `crossDomain` but you don't need it for your purpose. And `async:true` is redundant, since `true` is the default value. Regarding your actual problem, as Rory said check the response from ajax to ensure it actually contains all the correct headers. I'm not sure ajax+redirect is a great solution, since ajax does not automatically respond to redirect headers.

Comment: `http://api.example.com/post-data` would need to return the Access-Control-Allow headers in this case. You can of course not try and circumvent this restriction via a redirect in the background; the result will be pretty much the same as if you had made your AJAX request directly to the API URL in the first place.

Comment: So there just in no way i can check whether a redirect was successful or not?.

Comment: Here's the situation: your first ajax call must receive the "redirect" header, then make a second ajax request to the URl given in the header, which is just a waste of time really. On a normal postback the browser would read the header and handle this for you automatically, but ajax doesn't. So "checking whether the redirect was successful" doesn't make any sense because the redirect only happens _if you make it happen with your own code_. If you insist on doing this, then the response to your first ajax request (including the redirect header) must also include the CORS headers too.

Comment: I think you are imagining that the redirection happens on the server, but it doesn't, it must happen on the client.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your explanation and all others too.